# JqPlot: highlight series when hover over legend

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I've spent quiet some time today without success on finding the following out:

I want a trend-series to get the same highlight it gets from hovering over itself, when hovering over its legend entry:

***hover legend -> highlight series***.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

The other way around: ***hover series -> highlight legend***

I have this working by using the jqplotDataHighlight event handler like this

`$('#trendgraph').bind('jqplotDataHighlight', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data)`...

For pie and bar charts this works. but it doesnt work with trendgraphs?

Thanks for all help